# Traer datos a formulario de otra tabla seleccionando un campo en django

Tags: python, django

Solicito ayuda, tengo dos modelos, `Empleado` y `Liquidacion`, y un formulario `LiquidacionCrear`, necesito que al seleccionar el item `numerodocumento`, se cargue los campos que tengo relacionados(`OneToOneField`) con el modelo empleado.

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Empleado(models.Model):

    tdemp = models.ForeignKey(TipoDocumentoemp, null=True, blank=False,
                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ndemp = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=30, unique=True,
                    help_text="Numero Documento")
    ap1emp = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ap2emp = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    no1emp = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    no2emp = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

class Liquidacion(Empleado):
    numdemp = models.OneToOneField(Empleado, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,related_name='ndemp_empleado_set')
    tipdocemp = models.OneToOneField(Empleado, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='tdemp_empleado_set',null=True, blank=False)
    apell1emp = models.OneToOneField(Empleado, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='ap1emp_empleado_set')
    apell2emp = models.OneToOneField(Empleado, null=True, blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='ap2emp_empleado_set')
    nomb1emp = models.OneToOneField(Empleado, null=True, blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='no1emp_empleado_set')
    nomb2emp = models.OneToOneField(Empleado, null=True, blank=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='no2emp_empleado_set')
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
class LiquidacionCreate(CreateView):
    model = Liquidacion
    form_class = LiquidacionForm
    template_name = 'empleado/liquidacion_form.html'
    context_object_name = "obj"
    success_url = reverse_lazy('empleado:liquidacion_listar')
```

Archivo `forms.py`:

```
class Meta:
    

    widgets = {
        'numdemp': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'tipdocemp': forms.TextInput(),
        'apell1emp': forms.TextInput(),
        'apell2emp': forms.TextInput(),
        'nomb1emp': forms.TextInput(),
        'nomb2emp': forms.TextInput(),
    }
    
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in iter(self.fields):
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
        'class': 'form-control'
        })

    self.fields['numdemp'].empty_label = "Seleccione Empleado"
    self.fields['tipdocemp'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
    self.fields['apell1emp'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
    self.fields['apell2emp'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
    self.fields['nomb1emp'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
    self.fields['nomb2emp'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Necesito que cuando seleccione `'numdemp'` me llene los otros campos, del formulario. Agradezco, de antemano las sugerencias.

Comment: He analizado tu model.py y veo que haces muchas cosas raras.1- El modelo Liquidacion  tiene multiples OneToOneField solo debería de haber uno. 2. El modelo class Liquidacion(Empleado): utiliza a empleado en vez models.Model. 3. - a pesar de utilizar OneToOneField en los formularios forms.py llamas a TextInput como si fuese un CharField.

Answer (score 0):

**Form.py**

```
class LiquidacionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    numdemp = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Empleado.objects.all(), widget= forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), )
```

Leer la documentacion> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships

Comment: AttributeError: 'ModelChoiceField' object has no attribute 'to_field_name' ahora me arroja este error al aplicar el cambio en el form

Comment: para la primera opcion numdemp, el select funciona, pero no se cargan los demas campos del formulario, al aplicar le select. y es ahi donde tengo la duda, cual seria el metodo en la views.py o lo puedo hacer solo con el form.py.

Comment: @Jsierra2017 Si funciona el select, pues todo esta bien. Solo debes de guardar los datos correctamente en la base de datos.

Comment: He analizado tu model.py y veo que haces muchas cosas raras.1- El modelo Liquidacion  tiene multiples OneToOneField solo debería de haber uno. 2. El modelo class Liquidacion(Empleado): utiliza a empleado en vez models.Model. 3. - a pesar de utilizar OneToOneField en los formularios forms.py llamas a TextInput como si fuese un CharField.

Comment: Puede ser, pero tengo mis razones, todos los OneToOneField, son pk de liquidacion que necesito alimente mi nuevo formulario, como datos de solo lectura, y que luego de confirmar los utilizare para generar calculos, y guardarlos en mi modelo de bd liquidacion.no utilizo model.Model, por que necesito heredar los datos de Empleado.

Comment: Una solución es crear un ModelChoiceField para cada fila de ese formulario.  Pero no es practico si es el mismo dato para todos, por lo cual puedes crear una función  en tu vista   **def form_valid(self, form):**  y guardar el mismo dato de numdemp  para las demás filas

Comment: Seria un opcion, pero el detalle es que numdemp, es la pk  cuando hago el select en el formulario y  valide, se deben llenar los demas campos readonly automaticamente, solo verifico que estan ok y guardo, en la tabla con un button, que tengo definido. en le form.html. creo que mi dificultad esta en crear el metodo, aplicando el GET y el POST. llenar el formulario y enviarlo a la bd

Comment: Creo que entiendo lo que quieres hacer, pero solo necesitas una pk y traer todo los datos de ese OneToOneField.

Comment: una pequeña muestra como seria?